# Linux / wget with # gives the page with partial address

Tags: linux

I run the following url:

```
wget 'https://myurl:8080/address/index.html#part1;part2;part3;base/a/b;content'
```

It gives me the folloiwng:

```
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 4614 (4.5K) [text/html]
Saving to: “index.html”
```

It cuts before the '#', and downloads only the `index.html`. But I wish to get the page with the full address, which has a diffrent content.

Answer (score 0):

This is normal, because it is the same page. From [Wget with URL that contains #](https://superuser.com/a/487330/204979):

> `wget` is working fine. The [URI syntax](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986) specifies that the
> *[fragment](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986)* – the `#foo` part – is to be interpreted entirely client-side, and not used when retrieving the document
> itself.

That is, these two URLs are the same for `wget`:

```
https://myurl:8080/address/index.html#part1;part2;part3;base/a/b;content
https://myurl:8080/address/index.html
```

Comment: So I can't get the content of the full address? As I said, it is diffrent from the index.html page.

Comment: @MiddleWare yes, I believe it is, but `wget` is prepared to work like this. For it, it is like if you compare the link to this question with the link to one of these comments: both are the same page, only that you specify an internal anchor.

Comment: You can try with `curl`.

Comment: Let me try to make this a bit clearer.  Wget (and curl) are doing exactly what a web browser would be doing when you go to https://myurl:8080/address/index.html#part1;part2;part3;base/a/b;content, and loading the content from https://myurl:8080/address/index.html.  However, there is probably Javascript on that page that the browser then runs, and this is using the fragment identifier (#part1;part2;part3;base/a/b;content) to load different content.  You can see this behaviour in the Network section of your browser developer tools (press F12)